# JOIN по дате с округлением

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть таблица с полем типа DATETIME, которое хранит время и дату покупки:

```
order_date         |
--------------------
2017-03-20 17:37:00
2017-03-20 17:38:12
2017-03-20 18:21:58
2017-03-20 18:22:11
2017-03-20 18:24:58
```

И есть таблица суточных интервалов с шагом в 5 мин:

```
time   |
--------
00:00:00
00:05:00
00:10:00
...
23:45:00
23:50:00
23:55:00
```

Как можно посчитать количество покупок которые были сделаны в интервал времени?
т.е. в данном случаи должно получится:

```
time  | count
-------------
00:00  0
00:05  0
...    ...
17:35  2
18:20  3
...    ...
23:50  0
23:55  0
```

Comment: А если дат несколько, то все N часов за все дни в один интервал собирать ?

Comment: И 23:56 - это 23:55 или 00:00

Comment: @mike да можно о один

Comment: @mike 23:56 - 23:55

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM table1
JOIN table2
  ON table2.time BETWEEN TIME(tabel1.order_date) - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
                     AND TIME(tabel1.order_date)
```

Или наоборот. Или TIMEDIFF. Но вот эти варианты - фуллскан.

Comment: Не работает, `TIME(tabel1.order_date) - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE` - просто  отнимет 5 минут

Comment: Так и должно быть. А *не работать* - не может, запрос или работает, или даёт ошибку.

Comment: К примеру: время покупки `2017-03-20 17:37:00`, если сделать - `INTERVAL 5 MINUTE` то получится `2017-03-20 17:32:00` а должно быть `2017-03-20 17:35:00`. Т.е. последнее число в минутах должно быть 0 если последние число >= 0 и < 5, и 5 если последнее число >= 5 и <= 9

Comment: *время покупки 2017-03-20 17:37:00, если сделать - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE то получится 2017-03-20 17:32:00 а должно быть 2017-03-20 17:35:00.* Ну и чему будет равно `WHERE '2017-03-20 17:35:00' BETWEEN '2017-03-20 17:32:00' AND '2017-03-20 17:37:00'`, a?